# The navigation property was not found on the dependent type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I tried the other solutions from the other posts but none of them worked.

```
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int userID { get; set; }    

    public string username { get; set; }

    public string password { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Groups")]
    public virtual int groupID { get; set; }
}
```

relates to

```
public class Groups
{
    [Key]
    public int groupID { get; set; }
    public string groupName { get; set; }

}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Your `Users` class needs a property `public virtual Groups Group { get; set; }`

Comment: O so you just need to put a collection that will contain them?

Comment: Just an object (assuming `Users` has one `Groups`) or its `public ICollection<Groups> Groups { get; set; }` if `Users` contains multiple `Groups` (in which case you need to delete the `public virtual int groupID { get; set; }` property

Comment: The user will only have one group, I tried it with `public virtual Groups groupID { get; set; }` and im getting the error again.

Comment: Read my first comment :) - its `public virtual Groups Group { get; set; }` (and you keep the `public virtual int groupID { get; set; }`)

Comment: Suggest you work your way through [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj713564.aspx)

Comment: Alright it worked just one last thing, how come it auto generated a `Users_userID` from my `Groups` table?

Comment: That would have been be to associate the `Groups` with the `User` But you might need to run your migrations again now that you have added the correct navigation properties.

Comment: Ahhh alright thank you. Please post an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Ankit has already added an answer :)

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta, If you don't specifically provide a foreign key property,  it is created by Entity Framework automatically.

Comment: based from ankit's answer the `public int GroupID {get;set;}` isn't set to virtual. why is it like that? Isn't the FK required to be `virtual`?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta, virtual is applied on navigation properties to indicate lazy loading.

Comment: Only `Groups Group` needs to be virtual

Comment: ooooo alright got it, thank you so much to both of you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am assuming a One-Many relation between Group to User.

```
public class Group
{       
    [Key]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set;}
}
```

Approach 1: FK on navigation property

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int GroupID {get;set;}    
    [ForeignKey("GroupID ")]
    public virtual Group Group{ get; set; }
}
```

Approach 2: FK on key property

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Group")]
        public int GroupID {get;set;}    
        public virtual Group Group{ get; set; }
    }
```

The above nicely explained [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: Wow this is so convenient is this even legal? I don't have to do joins anymore. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, data annotations are convenient for small projects. But Fluent API is preferred when number of entities(tables) is large.